# Google Spreadsheets Repeat Function Nth Times & Sum Results

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following function

```
=IF(RAND()<0.25,1,0)
```

RAND() returns any value between 0 to 1 in decimal format and the idea is that an item has a 25% chance of getting a 1.  If it was less than 0.25 the rand() then its a hit and gets a 1 otherwise a 0.  Now lets say I need to do this 100 times and add up the sum of all the '1's that were created, which in this case will average to around 25 for 25%.  **How do I do this in Google Spreadsheets?**

**Basically looking for a way to repeat a function n'th amount of times and sum the results.**

I have looked around everywhere (youtube, google forums) and have not found any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may as well put this as an answer because it tries to address the broader question of whether you can repeat a function (say) 100 times. The answer is, yes if the function is compatible with an array formula. Rand can't be used in this way because it doesn't take any arguments (neither do some other functions like countifs for some reason). But you could get round it by using Randbetween instead and providing it with 100 array elements. These are multiplied by zero so don't actually affect the answer, but Google Sheets still evaluates the function 100 times:

```
ArrayFormula(sum(if(randbetween(0,A1:A100*0+99)<25,1,0)))
```

or

```
=Sumproduct(if(randbetween(0,A1:A100*0+99)<25,1,0))
```

The result is each time you force this to re-calculate (by changing something in the range A1:A100 or by setting File -> Spreadsheet Settings -> (Tab) Calculation -> Recalculation to every minute) it will give an answer around 25.

To make it more resilient (allow any value in A1:A100 including error values) could try

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(if(randbetween(0,iferror(A1:A100/0,0)+99)<25,1,0)))
```

or

```
=Sumproduct(if(randbetween(0,iferror(A1:A100/0,0)+99)<25,1,0))
```

I don't know why I didn't do this in the first place

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(if(randbetween(0,row(A1:A100)*0+99)<25,1,0)))
```

then this easily allows for a variable range

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(if(randbetween(0,row(indirect("A1:A"&H1))*0+99)<25,1,0)))
```

where the number in H1 doesn't have to be limited to the number of rows in the sheet.

Comment: I will give this a try, sounds way easier than what I came up with

Comment: Hopefully should be be useful. I've actually just spotted that putting a non-numeric value in A1:A100 would break the formula, so will add an alternative to my answer.

Comment: I just tried what you wrote, simply amazing answer :).  The edit is even better.  This is for sure the correct answer.  Way better than what I was doing.

Comment: That is really interesting how it evaluates A1:A100 even if nothing is there to simulate repetition of 100 times.  How did you figure this out?

Comment: By the way I should mention that if you want the '100' times to be based on a variable and be dynamic you could use my trick of turning that part of the formula into a string and using indirect.  This allows for this to happen dynamically :).

Comment: Yes good point, you could use indirect or possibly index to set up a variable range. I just thought that it would work like a regular array formula  and re-evaluate for each element in the range, but in this particular case you actually wanted to ignore the values in the array by putting them in an expression that always gave zero. The formula doesn't 'know' that the result doesn't depend on what's in A1:A100, so just goes ahead anyway.

Comment: And I have no idea why I didn't just use the Row() function instead. Will add that to my answer and your indirect suggestion.

Comment: Awesome solution :).  I'm sure many people will find this very useful! It's simply an amazing nth function and sum for google sheets as I've ever seen :).  Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed and good answer.

Comment: So I ran into an issue now where I have a percentage that is less than 1, what do I do now? I have 0.75% for example chance of something occurring? It seems this only works with percentages 1 through 100 in perfect integers.  I will see if I can find some solutions and post here but curious your opinions.

Comment: This could also apply for 99.9%, I only need accuracy to 2 decimal places, at most like .01% chance.  Maybe in this case I can do a random number between 0 and 10000?

Comment: So I did this and it seems to work, =ArrayFormula(sum(if(randbetween(0,row(indirect("A1:A"&100))*0+9999)<$I$3*10000,1,0))), this accounts for accuracy up to 0.0001 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a very convoluted answer.  If someone finds a better please let me know.

The first thing as the user |'-'| commented was to create a range on separate sheet.

Since I know that I will not be looking up more than 200 values at once I created my range to be 200 long of this formula.

```
=IF(RAND()<0.25,1,0)
```

This will create the initial list of random values.

The next step is you need to generate a randomizer seed.  Which is basically a random number between the range you created.  You can do this with

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,200)
```

This should be on the same column as what you are trying to sum up later.

Next you want to create a dynamic string that you can access via arrayFormula later.

```
="Randomizer!B"&B12&":B"&B12+B3
```

In my case I had the 200 random numbers on a sheet called randomizer.  Notice the &, this is how you connect strings.  In my example B12 is the reference to the `=RANDBETWEEN(1,200)`, and B3 is how many times I want the randomness to occur.  It can be any value as long as it's less than the randomizer seed by the amount of times you want it to be random.

Finally refer to this string using, `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(B13)))` , **indirect lets you refer to a string as a cell** and this is how I was able to create a dynamic range to calculate from.

I will say the advantage of this method is its super fast to calculate since the random numbers have been pre-computed.

**The idea is that it will keep creating random ranges from the precomputed random numbers you created, and then summing those ranges, essentially calculating random numbers n'th amount of times.**

Hope this helps someone.